# Arduino Serial Print Once: While Loop Doesn't Work?

Tags: while-loop, arduino

I wrote code for an Arduino Mega to count the number of times a rising edge occurs on pins 2 and 3 (interrupts). When I pull pin 4 low I want to print the number of counts from pins 2 and 3 once and not multiple times. I wrote a while loop to make sure that the values are printed when count_3 ==1, but even when count_3 is larger than 1 the values still print. I don't understand how this is possible. I've printed the values of count_3 inside the while loop to show that it is larger than 1 and it still prints when count_3 is larger than 1. How can it enter the while loop when it is larger than 1?! I must be missing something obvious..

```
long count_1 = 0;     //interrupt counter 1
long count_2 = 0;     //interrupt counter 2
int count_3 = 0;      //counter to trigger serial print


void increment_1() {      //1st ISR
  count_1++;
}

void increment_2() {      //2nd ISR
  count_2++;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);      // open the serial port at 9600 bps:
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), increment_1, RISING);   //Enable Interrupt
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3), increment_2, RISING);   //Enable Interrupt
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int sensorVal = digitalRead(4);   //read pin 4

  if (sensorVal == LOW) {
    count_3++;                      //increase count so program enters while loop once
  }

  while (count_3 == 1) {
    count_3++;                    //increase count3 so it never prints again
    Serial.println(count_3);
    Serial.print('\n');
    Serial.println(count_1);
    Serial.print('\n');
    Serial.println(count_2);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code does:

1. `loop()` is called again, again and again in never ending loop.
2. if `sensorVal` is HIGH nothing is happen
3. if `sensorVal` goes to LOW you must know how long it takes. For example 1 second
4. `count_3` is incremented in `if` statement and then is incremented in `while` statement, some data is printed.
5. next time `count_3` is incremented only in `if` statement. Type of `count_3` is `int`, so every 2^16(65536) increments overflow to 0 and then is again 1.
6. how many increment is done in 1s? Estimate one loop duration to 10µs, so it is 100000 increments. It is means values is printing approximately two times per second
7. `while` statement is here irrelevant. Better is use `if` statement

**Wrong approach**

Variables used in interrupts and in main code have to be declared as `volatile`. This is hint for compiler that variable can change any time and compiler do not use optimization for access to variable.

```
volatile long count_1 = 0;     //interrupt counter 1
volatile long count_2 = 0;     //interrupt counter 2
```

Access to variables changed in ISR from main code have to be does in atomic style. Otherwise wrong value can be read to main code. For example like this:

```
    long count_1_copy;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        count_1_copy = count_1;
    }
```